# What alternative can be used instead of if / else statements to make the code work in the same way?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to find way to make the code work the same way shown in the code below using the other methods to if/else statements. Can anyone help me with that? I have a lot more cities and clearly this isn't going to scale.

```
function getCityNameFromURL() {
    var curURL = "" + Request.ServerVariables("URL");
    var returnCityName = "";
    curURL = curURL.toLowerCase();

    if (curURL.indexOf("/sgncp/") != -1 || curURL.indexOf("/mlgct/") != -1)
        returnCityName = "London";
    if (
        curURL.indexOf("/berlinplus/") != -1 ||
        curURL.indexOf("/berlinadmin/") != -1
    )
        returnCityName = "Berlin";
    else if (
        curURL.indexOf("/tokyoplus/") != -1 ||
        curURL.indexOf("/tokyoadmin/") != -1
    )
        returnCityName = "Tokyo";
    else if (
        curURL.indexOf("/parisplus/") != -1 ||
        curURL.indexOf("/parisadmin/") != -1
    )
        returnCityName = "Paris";

    return returnCityName;
}
```

Comment: What's the goal you're trying to achieve by replacing the use of `if` / `else` statements?

Comment: Because I want to add more cities, but I dont want to continue adding more else if and having a long list. Just need something that would work alternative to this.

Comment: @Web1017 that's the sort of thing that should be in the question: i.e. "I have a lot more cities and clearly this isn't going to scale." It's the difference between a legit problem (not having long, tedious, repetitive, hard-to-maintain code) and pointless wankery ("conditionals r bad because some book said so").

Answer (score 5):

How about a more simple configuration based code? You could even move the city mapping info in to a separate resource.

This would allow simpler updates without having to write extra code.

```
function getCityNameFromURL() {
    var curURL = "" + Request.ServerVariables("URL");
    curURL = curURL.toLowerCase();

    var cityMappings = [
        { code: '/sgncp/', city: 'London' },
        { code: '/mlgct/', city: 'London' },
        { code: '/berlinplus/', city: 'Berlin' },
        { code: '/berlinadmin/', city: 'Berlin' },
        { code: '/tokyoplus/', city: 'Tokyo' },
        { code: '/tokyoadmin/', city: 'Tokyo' },
        { code: '/parisplus/', city: 'Paris' },
        { code: '/parisadmin/', city: 'Paris' }
    ];

    return cityMappings
        .find(mapping => curURL.indexOf(mapping.code) >= 0)
        ?.city ?? '';
}
```

Note also, the null-conditional `?.` when attempting to access the `city` property just incase the URL doesn't match any of them and returns an empty string.

**Version with for loop**

Replace the cityMappings.find code with this

```
    for (let i = 0; i < cityMappings.length; i++){
        const mapping = cityMappings[i];
        if (curURL.indexOf(mapping.code) >= 0)
            return mapping.city;
    }

    // in case no match was found return an emtpy string.
    return '';
```

Comment: Thats could work. I am trying to get to be much simpler than having a huge list with if else statements

Comment: Is it possible to make this part inside a for loop instead?                                                       .find(mapping => curURL.indexOf(mapping.code) >= 0)
        ?.city ?? '';

Comment: Yes, but why would you want to? You'd have to introduce an extra loop variable and the JavaScript engine will likely already be doing this as part of the implementation of `Array.prototype.find()` and likely be more efficient about it too.

Comment: I understand. I want to try it within a for loop as well as later I would make more changes and work with the one that's best.

Comment: @Web1017 Added a for loop version.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is very similar to [the one already given by phuzi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70543169/3982562).

This answer also introduces a city mapping, but in a somewhat different manner to reduce string duplication. I've also introduced a `defaultCity` variable to (arguably) improve code readability.

```
function getCityNameFromURL() {
  const curURL = ("" + Request.ServerVariables("URL")).toLowerCase();

  const defaultCity = { name: "" };
  const cities = [
    { name: "London", patterns: ["/sgncp/",      "/mlgct/"      ] },
    { name: "Berlin", patterns: ["/berlinplus/", "/berlinadmin/"] },
    { name: "Tokyo",  patterns: ["/tokyoplus/",  "/tokyoadmin/" ] },
    { name: "Paris",  patterns: ["/parisplus/",  "/parisadmin/" ] },
  ];

  const city = cities.find(({ patterns }) => (
    patterns.some(pattern => curURL.includes(pattern))
  )) || defaultCity;

  return city.name;
}
```

Or if you prefer a for-loop:

```
for (const { name, patterns } of cities) {
  for (const pattern of patterns) {
    if (curURL.includes(pattern)) return name;
  }
}

return "";
```